# configure.in or configure.ac?

Tags: c, unix, autotools, autoconf

It seems that some autoconf projects use a `configure.in` file to generate a `configure` script, and some use `configure.ac`.

What is the difference/advantage between using one or the other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its just a matter of style.  Historically autoconf files were named `configure.in`.  Now `configure.ac` is the preferred naming scheme.  Its also discussed in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Writing-Autoconf-Input.html#Writing-Autoconf-Input).

Comment: No, it's not just style.  The name configure.in is deprecated.

Comment: Even the docs say preferred.  I've never noticed a deprecation warning, but then again I think all my projects use .ac.

Comment: I just checked the docs and you are right.  Not yet fully deprecated.  I'm nearly certain I have seen deprecation warnings, but perhaps not in an official release.

Answer (score 11):

New projects should use configure.ac.  Old projects used configure.in; if it is inconvenient to switch to the new name, they can continue to use it, but the autoconf tools will generate a warning.

Comment: The current version of `autoconf` (1.13.1 as of 2013-01-01) still supports `configure.ac`, but the [release notes](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2013-01/msg00000.html) say "_Automake 1.14 will drop support for the long-deprecated 'configure.in'
  name for the Autoconf input file.  You are advised to start using the
  recommended name 'configure.ac' instead, ASAP._"

Comment: Yup, now they have finally moved forward with deprecating it.

Comment: In my first comment, there's a typo — it should be '_still supports `configure.in` ...'_ as `configure.ac` is the future direction.